# Can we express every Boolean function as a Boolean formula of polynomial size?

Tags: combinatorics, computational-complexity, boolean-algebra

Can every Boolean function over $n$ variables be expressed as a Boolean formula of size polynomial to $n$?

Comment: Boolean formula of the form $(P\lor Q\lor \neg R)\wedge(\neg P\wedge Q)$, does not have to be CNF or anything standard form.

Comment: @AsafRosemarin
Your answer was good in my opinion. I don't think you should have deleted it, just edit.

Comment: @HuiWang Can you please put that comment into the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is no.

We know that there are functions requiring $\Omega(2^n/n)$ logic gates to compute using [boolean circuit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_circuit), which is equivalent to polynomial length formula.
(Since both evaluating a circuit or a formula with a given assignment is in P.)

One could prove such "hard function" exists using counting the number of functions versus the number of circuits see [this](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/82274/113091) for example.

Those function existence does not mean we know how to find one. So, unfortunately, there are no examples.

Comment: Sorry, do you mean $\Omega(2^n/n)$ logic gates or input gates?

Comment: I don't think it matters, but I meant logic, thanks!

Comment: I believe the result for formulas is $\Omega(\frac{2^n}{\log{n}})$ but yes your answer is still correct.